# Weird javadoc error (with jdk12) for OSGi version annotation

Tags: java, osgi, javadoc, java-12

With the change from Java 11 to Java 12, we now see a weird error when generating Javadoc on package-info files containing OSGi version annotations.

The source code is:

```
@Version("1.3.0")
package org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.commons;

import org.osgi.annotation.versioning.Version;
```

The error is:

```
[ERROR] C:\projects\apache\oak\trunk\oak-commons\src\main\java\org\apache\jackrabbit\oak\commons\package-info.java:17: error: unknown tag: Version
[ERROR] @Version("1.3.0")
[ERROR] ^
```

([See details and context](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OAK-8149))

Is this a regression in Java 12, or is there something wrong in the way the annotations are used, or how Javadoc is invoked (through maven)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably a Javadoc bug, because Javadoc considers the Java Annotation as a **Javadoc Tag**.

**Workaround 1:**
disable this Javadoc tag

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>                        
                    <tags>
                        <tag>
                            <name>Version</name>                            
                            <placement>X</placement>                            
                        </tag>
                    </tags>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

**Workaround 2:**
add an empty Javadoc block in front of every annotation

```
/** */@Version("1.3.0")
package org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.commons;
```

Comment: Thanks. The workaround (1) works for us and shows that it's indeed a confusion with Javadoc tags. Filed bug report (9060468).

Comment: Does the maven-javadoc-plugin print anything useful when mvn is run with -X (or --debug)? It would be useful if the command that the plugin is using in case it's anything obvious.

Comment: It *does* print a whole lot of information: https://gist.github.com/reschke/b7eab88822ec63f7d80d46902ff62f09

Answer (score 3):

The fix is to upgrade to a newer JDK version.

The issue affects JDK 12, and was fixed in JDK 13 by [JDK-8222091: Javadoc does not handle package annotations correctly on package-info.java](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8222091).

The same issue also affects OpenJDK 11.0.17, because the change that introduced the javadoc regression was backported. It was fixed in JDK 11.0.18. (See https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8295850.)

Simplified repro:

```java
package p;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.PACKAGE;

import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(PACKAGE)
public @interface A {}
```

```java
@A
package p;
```

```
$ javadoc package-info.java A.java
...
package-info.java:1: error: unknown tag: A
@A
^
```